# Phonegap fires keyboarddown and keyboardup on pressing the auto rotate button in the android pulldown menu

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Phonegap fires keyboarddown and keyboardup on pressing the auto rotate button in the android pulldown menu. Does anyone know how this is possible. I got this as event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('showkeyboard',hideNavbar, false);
    document.addEventListener('hidekeyboard',showNavbar, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
    history.go(-1);
    navigator.app.backHistory();
}
function onMenuKeyDown() {
    $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
}
function hideNavbar(){
    $(".navbar").hide(500);
}
function showNavbar(){
    $(".navbar").show(500);
}
```